# What exactly does the := operator do in Elm?

Tags: operators, elm, colon-equals

Here is an unclear example from docs, using this operator: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Json-Decode#at

Comment: Please explain what you do not understand or what is not working. I am voting to close this question as *Unclear what you are asking*

Comment: Wow, after all the replies It's all clear. Many thanks to everyone. I could not understand that this operator is specific for Json.Decode package, I thought it origins from core.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please note that [**(:=)**](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Json-Decode#:=) is removed from [Json.Decode](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/) starting from `0.18.0`

## Infix operators

In Elm, you can define custom [infix operators](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#infix-operators), the purpose of their existence is for providing a more readable version of the code. Ironically, when you're not familiar with the concept, it does the opposite.

[**(:=)**](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Json-Decode#:=) is a custom infix operator, provided by [Json.Decode](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/) package.

Please consider the following example of a custom infix operator:

```elm
import Html exposing (text)

(<|>) : String -> String -> String
(<|>) beginning end =
  beginning ++ "Bar" ++ end

main =
  text ("Foo" <|> "Buz") -- "FooBarBuz"
```

It is highly recommended to avoid usage of custom infix operators.

Let's get back to [**(:=)**](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Json-Decode#:=) operator.

The type definition for it looks like `(:=) : String -> Decoder a -> Decoder a`, which means, that we have to pass a String and a Decoder, from the list of available [Decoder Primitives](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Json-Decode#primitives) and reruns a new decoder, with a string key mapped to it.

## Native Code

In JavaScript world, Decoders are callback functions that do type checking.

For example, here is a Decoder String Primitive:

```js
function decodeString(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String) {
    return value;
  }
  crash('a String', value);
}
```

And here's a JavaScript equivalent of [**(:=)**](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Json-Decode#:=) operator:

```js
function decodeField(field, decoder) {
  return function(value) {
    var subValue = value[field];
    if (subValue !== undefined) {
      return decoder(subValue);
    }
    crash("an object with field '" + field + "'", value);
  };
}
```

## TL;DR

[**(:=)**](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Json-Decode#:=) maps a string key to a callback (it's not exactly a callback, but that's the closest you could think of), which will check the type of the value in JavaScript object, when you convert it into Elm value.

Answer (score 5):

It creates a decoder for the given key in a json string.

```
"name" := string
```

Creates a decoder that extracts the value in "name" and passes it to the `string` decoder.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a key for the dictionary you're operating on and attempts to decode what's found there with a decoder, such as any of the built in ones or even your own custom one.

It's essentially a single access `at`.

```
at ["name"] string
```

Is equal to:

```
"name" := string
```